# Please enable JavaScript to continue using this application

Tags: angular

In the development environment everything is normal, but it happens with the project in production.

The problem appeared after disabling the service worker, but I enabled it again and nothing happens. The problem continues!!!

How to fix the problem? Can you show me the way?

***AppModule***

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,

    CoreModule,

    LayoutModule,

    ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production })
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

***package.json***

```
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.1.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "~10.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "~10.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "~10.1.2",
    "@angular/service-worker": "~10.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "lodash-es": "4.17.15",
    "ngx-mask": "^11.1.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.6",
    "sweetalert2": "^10.15.7",
    "tslib": "^2.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1001.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.1.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/lodash-es": "4.17.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.5",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "lodash": "4.17.15",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.0.7"
  }
}
```

Comment: didnt find any solution?

Comment: same issue, any solutions 2022?